# How to use a Variable in Jmeter Regex Extractor

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to jMeter. I am recording a script for creating a shift. For every transaction New shift ID is generated. I have tried to extract it by using regx Exp extractor but not getting anything. Pls see below information.

*Reference Name: **strgenShiftId**

Regular Expression: **end="${strWeekEndDate}" gs="(.+?)"**

Template: **$1$**

Match No.

Default Value:

Where **${strWeekEndDate}** is a variable which extracts the date from some other previous response.

***My Response code is as following-***

**week start="07/27/2015" end="08/02/2015" gs="61530" unitSkey="811" fy="2015" fw="30" ac="Y">**

I want to extract the gs="61531".

The full response is:

```
<data>
<weeks selWkIndex="5">
<week start="06/29/2015" end="07/05/2015" gs="71526" unitSkey="811" fy="2015" fw="26" ac="N">
</week>
<week start="07/06/2015" end="07/12/2015" gs="71527" unitSkey="811" fy="2015" fw="27" ac="N">
</week>
<week start="07/13/2015" end="07/19/2015" gs="71528" unitSkey="811" fy="2015" fw="28" ac="N">
</weeks>
</data>
```

Comment: Can you paste your code as is?

Comment: @Shawn Please find following response -                                              
<data><weeks selWkIndex="5"><week start="06/29/2015" end="07/05/2015" gs="71526" unitSkey="811" fy="2015" fw="26" ac="N"></week><week start="07/06/2015" end="07/12/2015" gs="71527" unitSkey="811" fy="2015" fw="27" ac="N"></week><week start="07/13/2015" end="07/19/2015" gs="71528" unitSkey="811" fy="2015" fw="28" ac="N">

Comment: I added your output to your question for readability. Thanks.

Comment: Add a debug post processor in order to be sure that the value of strWeekEndDate is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract gs value using following regular expression: `gs=\"([^"]+)\"`. Always remember to escape `"` with `\` in regular epressions, unless you want `"` to be evaluated as part of regular expression.